# Substitution fails

Tags: bash, unix, substitution

I'm trying to create a variable name using the value of another variable.
First, other examples of code I am writing that do work:

```
#!/bin/bash
j=0
let "AVG_T_${j}"+="(${TEMPS[$j]})" #Works
let "tLen"="(${#AVG_T_0[@]})" #Works
tLen=${#AVG_T_0[@]} #Works
let "AVG_T_0=${AVG_T_0[@]:1}" #Works
let "AVG_T_${j}"="${AVG_T_0[@]:1}" #Works
```

This is what I am having trouble with:

```
#!/bin/bash
j=0
"tLen"="(${#AVG_T_${j}[@]})" #Bad Substitution
let "AVG_T_${j}"="${AVG_T_${j}[@]:1}" #Bad Substitution
```

I do not know of a way make it work. I've tried many different syntaxes, brackets, without, etc.
I don't know where to go from here with it.

Thanks

Here is where I am at now. The code is supposed to check the temperatures of the temperature zones and then give output for current and for an averaged output.

```
j=0
TEMPS=()
AVGtn=5
DIRECTORY="/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone"${j}
while [ -d "$DIRECTORY" ];
do
    eval "AVG_T_${j}_TOTAL="""
    TEMPS+=($(cat $DIRECTORY/temp))
    TEMPS[$j]=$(convert ${TEMPS[$j]})
    eval "AVG_T_${j}+=(\"\${TEMPS[${j}]}\")"
    eval "tLen=\${#AVG_T_${j}[@]}" #Works
    if [ $tLen -gt $AVGtn ]; then
      eval "AVG_T_${j}=(\"\${AVG_T_${j}[@]:1}\")"
      eval "tLen=\${#AVG_T_${j}[@]}"
      AVG_T=()
      eval "AVG_T+=(\"\${AVG_T_${j}[@]}\")"
      for i in ${AVG_T[@]}; do
        let "AVG_T_${j}_TOTAL"+=${i}
       done
      eval "x=\${AVG_T_${j}_TOTAL}"
      let "AVG_TMP_${j}=(1000*($x/$tLen)+5)/1000"
    fi
    let "j++"
    DIRECTORY="/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone"${j}
    sleep 3
done
```

This is what I finally ended up with. I know it could be tightened and cleaned up, but I'm happy just to have working code. Maybe it will help some other layman like myself to keep moving forward.

```
  j=0
  TEMPS=()
  DIRECTORY="/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone"${j}
  while [ -d "$DIRECTORY" ];
    do
      # Put TOTAL to null
      eval "AVG_T_${j}_TOTAL="""
      # Add one directory temp to TEMPS
      TEMPS+=($(cat $DIRECTORY/temp))
      # Convert TEMP to Celsius
      TEMPS[$j]=$(convert ${TEMPS[$j]})
      # Put the converted TEMP into AVG_T_n
      eval "AVG_T_${j}+=(\"\${TEMPS[${j}]}\")"
      # Get the current Length of AVG_T_n
      eval "tLen=\${#AVG_T_${j}[@]}"
      # If the len of AVG_T_n is greater than AVGtn
      if [ $tLen -gt $AVGtn ]; then
        # Take Oldest temp out of Array
        eval "AVG_T_${j}=(\"\${AVG_T_${j}[@]:1}\")"
        # Reset tLen Length to the new length
        eval "tLen=\${#AVG_T_${j}[@]}"
      fi
      # Clear AVG_T
      AVG_T=()
      # Get an AVG_T_${j} duplicate duplicate from eval named AVG_T so we can use it as a condition that the for loop understands
      eval "AVG_T+=(\"\${AVG_T_${j}[@]}\")"
      # Add all of AVG_T values together and put into AVG_T_n_TOTAL
      for i in ${AVG_T[@]}; do
        let "AVG_T_${j}_TOTAL"+=${i}
      done
      # Ceate a variable with eval so that we can use it in the formula that provides the average temperature
      eval "x=\${AVG_T_${j}_TOTAL}"
      # Create the AVG_TMP_n
      eval let "AVG_TMP_${j}=\"(1000*(\$x/\$tLen)+5)/1000\""
      # Convert the AVG_TMP_n to Fahrenheit
      eval let "AVG_TMP_${j}f=\"\$(convertc2f AVG_TMP_${j})\""
      # Create another variable for echo for testing
      let "j++"
        DIRECTORY="/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone"${j}
  done
```

Comment: Please paste your code in https://www.shellcheck.net/, your error will pop up in a matter of seconds!

Comment: I tried shellcheck.net but I wasn't getting the correct suggestions for what I was doing. But  tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `eval`.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -exu
declare -a AVG_T_0=(first second third fourth)

j=0
eval "tLen=\${#AVG_T_${j}[@]}"
eval "AVG_T_${j}=(\"\${AVG_T_${j}[@]:1}\")"
typeset -p tLen
typeset -p AVG_T_0
typeset -p "AVG_T_${j}"
```

Comment: Thanks for that help Feng. I am still working on my code, but your eval has helped me simplify things. I'll post what code I have so far.